# Show Order Details in Order History

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, frontend

Basically I want to show Customer's Order Details information in order History page under Customer Account **My Order History** Page.

**Exactly what I'm did?**

I have overridden

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/history.phtml

through below layout change :

```
<!--app/code/Btech/OrderTracking/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_history.xml -->

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Btech_OrderTracking::css/custom.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.history">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Btech_OrderTracking::order/history.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

In my **history.phtml**

> app/code/Btech/OrderTracking/view/frontend/templates/order/history.phtml

```
    <div id="accordion" data-mage-init='{
            "accordion":{
                "active": [1,2],
                "collapsible": true,
                "openedState": "active",
                "multipleCollapsible": true
            }}'>

    <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
        <div data-role="collapsible">
                <div data-role="trigger">
                    <h4><?php echo $_order->getRealOrderId() ?></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                Want to Show Order Items
            </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**I want like as like below screen :**

[image]

Comment: you can use paid module of mageants [order history](https://www.mageants.com/order-history-for-magento-2.html) extension it will work as per request you can test demo available there

Answer (score 2):

Supravat. I guess that you want to get Content from `www.example.com/sales/order/view/order_id/{OrderId}/` when clicking into `<h4>`

In that, I suggest is that implement [**ajaxContent of Collapsible widget**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_collapsible.html)

that call `www.example.com/sales/order/view/order_id/{OrderId}/` and get content of  HTML out  of Block `sales.order.view`.

```
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\View" name="sales.order.view" cacheable="false" after="sales.order.info.links">
```

At this case, send an extra parameter name  `visited_from`  to url **`www.example.com/sales/order/view/order_id/{OrderId}/visited_from/orderview`**
to identify that request coming from that your custom Url

After that for getting the out of  particular Block `sales.order.view`  use  Plugin on `\Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\View::execute`

and Using **around** plugin **aroundExecute** only response `sales.order.view`  section of block.

### Plugin Class

```
<?php


namespace StackExchange\Magento\Plugin\Controller\Order;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoaderInterface;

class ViewPlugin 
{

    /**
     * @var OrderLoaderInterface
     */
    private $orderLoader;


    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    private $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        OrderLoaderInterface  $orderLoader   
     ) {

         $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
         $this->orderLoader = $orderLoader;
    }
     public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\View $subject,
        \Closure $proceed    
     ) {
         if($subject->getRequest()->getParam('visited_from') == 'orderview'){

            $result = $this->orderLoader->load($subject->getRequest());
            if ($result instanceof \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface) {
                return $result;
            }

            $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            $response = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('sales.order.view')->toHtml();
            return $subject->getResponse()->setBody($response);            
         }

         // run original  Method
         return $proceed();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please explain how cam I use `ajaxContent` and also call  url `www.example.com/sales/order/view/order_id/{OrderId}/`